# Cambiar mensaje de error en un input con min y max

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este input

```
<input type="number" name="dni" min="9999999">
```

Quiero hacer que el mensaje de error que este input genere al poner un 1 o cualquier numero menor al indicado pueda ser escrito por mi

```
required oninvalid="return this.setCustomValidity('El Valor es incorrecto.')"
```

Con el required oninvalid logre que lo haga pero tambien lo hace con todos los errores, por ejemplo, poner una letra

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer con javaScript. Comprueba que el contenido de #dni es numero, por ejemplo, divide el numero entre 1, si se permite, es numero, si te da un error, es String. Dentro de esa condicion, si #dni es numero y es menor que el numero que tu quieres, utiliza el codigo que te funciona, y en el else, pon que tiene que introducir un numero.